# Can I use "linkography" instead of "bibliography" when referring to web links?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, is-it-a-word, citation, tech-writing

I’m writing a piece of documentation and I want to add the links I'm referring to at the bottom of my document.

Since they are links and not books, I think the section title should not use the word *bibliography*.

The most appropriate term that comes to mind is *linkography*. However, I don't know if this word even exists. I did not find it in the dictionary. I think the word is ugly, and my computer’s spell-checker does not know it.

Is *linkography* the best term to use when referring to web links? Does this word really exist?

Comment: While the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=LINKOGRAPHY) is hardly an authoritative reference, the fact that *linkography* is in there means somebody has used it. But if you'd rather use the word *bibliography*, nobody is going to object that you're using it for links rather than books. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bibliography) defines it as *"a list of the books, magazines, articles, etc., that are mentioned in a text"*. I think *links* clearly fall under the category of *"etc."*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd avoid "Linkography", as readers are unlikely to be familiar with it.

You can write "References" instead.  This works for links as well as books.

By the way, be careful of the [etymological fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy).  The word *bibliography* may contain *biblio-*, but that doesn't determine its meaning in the modern language.  To figure that out, you need to consult a [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bibliography) or look at actual usage.

Comment: "References" is perfect. Thanks!