# How to name collection of web links?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, terminology, is-it-a-word, tech-writing

I have a blog and from time to time I made posts that contains only web links with some short description. Those links was not so easy to gather and they are have a value by themselves. I call this kind of posts as "Link Set" and you can see for example [this linkset](https://stokito.wordpress.com/2015/07/28/linkset-migration-to-java-8/).
This is some kind of shared bookmarks with comments.

What is interesting that today I found another Russian-speaker blogger who also used the similar term "Link List" and [here is his example of linklist](https://felixit.blog/erlixir/) about some new programming language. Which means that this is quite useful kind of information.

So my main question is how to name such kind of posts? I see several options:

1. "Link Set" - I googled and it seems not used but in the same time I found a [definition](https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/featureconcept/LinkSet) "A collection of link sequences and/or individual links that has a specific function or significance in a network" which is still not clear.
2. "Link List" - may be more clear but still not used and in the same time it may disambiguate with [Linked List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) but it has different spelling.
3. Traditional "Bibliography" term is good but it has some another meaning like an attachment to some article with list of sources. Here I found some related term [Linkography](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133638/can-i-use-linkography-instead-of-bibliography-when-referring-to-web-links).
4. References: used by WikiPedia but in my opnion it have some another meaning. Anyway this is a good candidate.
5. Bookmarks: This term looks like have a more precise meaning.
6. Pinterest.com uses term "pin"
7. Links Collection : as very clear term but to be honest is harder to pronounce. The [dropmark.com](https://dropmark.com) uses just a term "Collection".

So can you advice me on this? I'm not a native speaker so any feedback from native speakers will be very helpful.

Comment: I would just say *list of websites*. (However, that's just me—it could be any number of things. There is no set phrase.) But if it's at the end of a paper, they are simply listed along with every other source in the section called *References*, *Works Cited*, *Endnotes*, *Bibliography*, or whatever it is your style guide says you should name such a list.

Comment: People use "Resources" for this.

Answer (score 1):

"Annotated bookmarks" makes sense to me. So, number 5 with qualification. A bookmark would be just the link. But you have provided some description of each link. So that's presumably more valuable than just the link.